# googleapp engine hello world 500 server error?

Tags: google-app-engine

Trying out the hello world tutorial for googleapp engine. But get the 500 server error when I try to go on the deployed app.

```
http://chemstest.appspot.com/
```

The index works, but then the servlet gives me the error. Its written in java. I saw some things about case errors in web.xml but the app name and java class are all named in lowercase.

The servlet:

```
package com.chems.hellogoogleapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class hellogoogleappServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, James");
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hellogoogleapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.chems.hellogoogleapp.hellogoogleappServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hellogoogleapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hellogoogleapp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

appengine-xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>chemstest</application>
  <version>1</version>

  <!--
    By default, App Engine sends requests serially to a given web server.
    To allow App Engine to send multiple requests in parallel specify:

      <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  -->

  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>

</appengine-web-app>
```

Hopefully an easy one to solve?

Comment: Error: Not Found

The requested URL /hellogoogleapp was not found on this server.

Comment: That just because I was trying it with all upper case H. Same both ways :(

Comment: So probably not an easy one to solve?

Comment: Do you have anything on the server side logs?

Comment: I fixed this Roger, I can't remember what it was causing the problem now. Something basic I'd missed thou.